# c# 3.5 - sharing authentication between winforms and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, winforms, forms-authentication

I have a winforms application which calls web services and then based on the results fires up an ASP.NET webpage.

The ASP.NET webpage and web services are protected by a custom membership provider. At present the user has to log in to their winforms app and then also into the asp.net webpage. Is there a way to only have to log in to the winforms app and somehow share whatever authentication state exists with the ASP.NET webpage?

I've seen [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - however it seems to be more aimed at sharing authentication between server applications, not two client applications.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the mechanism that WinForms uses for authentication.

Comment: Its authenticating against a webservice using Forms authentication, this grants access to the other webservices

Comment: Most likely the WinForms app just sends the credentials to the web services as a part of the request.  Chances are the credentials are temporarily stored in the app and sent with all other web service requests, because web services do not typically support a notion of an authentication state.

I doubt there is much you can do here aside from passing the credentials when you launch the browser to the ASP.NET page, but it would be very unsafe.  

Since this all seems like an internal system, why don't you switch to integrated authentication?